# How to convert a batch file stored in utf-8 to something that works via another batch file and run it

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a program I use to create a batch file. My problem is that the program's output is UTF-8 so as soon as any diacritical marks like é,à,ö,Ä are in my batch file it fails.
It seems I can't figure out a way to convert my output to anything but UTF-8 in the program that creates the batch file.

So I was thinking of creating two bach files. The actual one and another that converts the actual one from UTF-8 to ANSI (Windows Codepage 1252, or maybe cp 850) and then executes it after that. Of course I'd add a chcp xxxx as the first command of the actual batch file.

So my question is is there an alternative to iconv on Windows - or how does one convert a UTF-8 text file to a windows codepage using a second batch file. Is there anything built into Win XP and up that I could use or is there a free and redistributable tool I might use for this?

Note:

```
chcp 65001
```

does not work for batch files.

**EDIT 1:**

on windows XP I created two batch files to test the first answer.

1.bat encoded to UTF-8 without BOM contains:

```
chcp 1252
cd üöä
```

2.bat also encoded to UTF-8 without BOM - but without any special characters contains:

```
chcp 1252
type "1.bat" >"ansi_file.bat"
```

The resulting ansi_file.bat created when one executes 2.bat will still be utf-8 encoded and not ansi encoded.

**EDIT 2:**

The mentioned reverse process works.

```
chcp 1252
echo ü > ansi.txt
cmd /u /c type ansi.txt > unicode.txt
```

but neither of the following subsequent lines

```
cmd /a /c type unicode.txt > back2ansi.txt
type unicode.txt > back2ansi_v2.txt
```

gets me back to ANSI. I tried this both on Win XP and Win 7.
Can anyone help?

**NOTE:**

I'm aware of how to use the Windows Script Host and VBS. I'd like to avoid depending on the script host though. The VBS method is detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**EDIT 3:**

The text file created containing a unicode ü above is not utf-8

The Windows unicode file is HEX:

```
FC 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00
```

UTF-8 without BOM would be HEX:

```
C3 BC 20 0D 0A
```

The VBS solution linked to only works with the unicode form but fails on the UTF-8 form.
I need to convert UTF-8 to another code page so not even that one seems to work for me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have stated you don't want to rely on the script host, but there is no native batch command that can do what you want. You are going to have to use *something* beyond pure batch. The script host is native to Windows, so I should think it would not be a problem.

The following **UTF8toANSI.vbs** script converts UTF-8 (with or without BOM) into ISO-8859-1, (basically the same as code page 1252). It is adapted from [VB6/VbScsript change file / write file with encoding to ansii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186170/1012053).

```
Option Explicit

Private Const adReadAll = -1
Private Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
Private Const adTypeText = 2
Private Const adWriteChar = 0

Private Sub UTF8toANSI(ByVal UTF8FName, ByVal ANSIFName)
  Dim strText

  With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .LoadFromFile UTF8FName
    .Type = adTypeText
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    strText = .ReadText(adReadAll)
    .Position = 0
    .SetEOS
    .Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    .WriteText strText, adWriteChar
    .SaveToFile ANSIFName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
  End With
End Sub

UTF8toANSI WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)
```

The VBS script would need to be in your current directory or your path.

A batch script to convert and run your UTF8 encoded script could look something like this:

```
@echo off
UTF8toANSI "utf8.bat" "ansi.bat"
ansi.bat
```

***Original Answer:*** *below is my original answer that works for UTF-16 with BOM, but not for UTF-8*

The output of internal commands is automatically converted to ANSI if output is piped or redirected to a file.

```
chcp 1252
type "utf_file.bat" >"ansi_file.bat"
```

The process can go in reverse if CMD is started with the `/U` option, but unfortunately the unicode header bytes will be missing. But of course that is a non-issue for your situation.

Comment: I'm trying this with Win XP but can't get it to work, can you elaborate some more?

Comment: I added what I tried and found to my question for you to look at.

Comment: I have added more information to the question and have started a bounty on it as I still can't make this work...

Comment: This answer is currently wrong. type "input.bat" > "output.bat" only works for a UCS-2 encoded input unicode file with a proper byte order mark. UTF-8 != USC-2.

Comment: Yes I have come up with pretty much the same thing in the meantime. I'm not converting to ANSI though but convert to UCS-2 by .Charset("unicode") and use your original type in.txt > out.txt to convert to the OEM code page. This way it will work on various languages of windows which is important to me. I have one problem with it however and that is that while on Win XP it works fine on Windows 7 I get two characters at the start of the UCS-2 file that don't belong there. It looks like even though the UTF-8 file has no BOM the ADODB.Stream treats it as though it had one on Windows 7...

Comment: @C.O. - You could modify the VBS to take a 3rd argument as the charset specifier, instead of using a hard-coded value. Here is some documentation for the charset property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526296(v=exchg.10).aspx

Answer (score 7):

In Unix I would use the "iconv" tool for converting between encodings:

```
iconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code iso-8859-1 -c inputfile > outputfile
```

It seems a build for Windows is avialable at  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned Iconv in the question but I'm not looking for a redistributable additional program but would prefer a solution using what windows ships with.

Answer (score 0):

You can get many GNU command line utilities from the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project. That includes `iconv` (and many more):

```
C:\> iconv.exe -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 input.bat > output.bat
```

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned Iconv in the question but I'm not looking for a redistributable additional program but would prefer a solution using what windows ships with.