# ASCII Code [☢] in Batch

Tags: batch-file, ascii

Ive tried pasting this character: ☢ into a txt file,but when I use TYPE,it doesn't show the symbol? Is there a certain code page?
Tried different encoding options.
I know about the `CHCP` command and tried different pages.

Comment: that's not an ascii code. there's never been a nuke symbol in ascii. that'd be a utf character...

Comment: This is not an ASCII character, this is UTF8. Make sure your encoding is UTF8. If I paste it into an UTF8 document it is shown, it doesn't work with other encoding. EDIT: beaten by 25 seconds

Comment: try to use: `chcp 65001` which will set encoding to `UTF8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your file has the UTF8 BOM (Use Notepad++ or the option suggested in the answers below), then you may need to change the character set of your console with `chcp 65001`, see this answers for more information:

- [How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default)
- [How to convert a batch file stored in utf-8 to something that works via another batch file and run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130214/how-to-convert-a-batch-file-stored-in-utf-8-to-something-that-works-via-another)

Answer (score 3):

As Josep indicates, the text file containing the UTF-8 character has to be encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.

Also, your console font has to include that character. The default fonts don't. I just tested [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org), and it works. See [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/) for instructions on how to add a TrueType font to the cmd console.

Finally, you can get around messing with the code page garbage by invoking powershell.  That way you don't have to mess with scraping the current code page, changing it to 65001, doing your thing, then restoring back to original.  Just do this:

```
powershell "gc nuke.txt"
```

... where nuke.txt contains ☢

---

Edit: Since you're unable to install new fonts on your computer, the only solution is [ascii art](http://www.retrojunkie.com/asciiart/logos/nuclear.htm).

```
   ___
   \_/
.--,O.--,
 \/   \/
```

Comment: What font is your console using?  Try it with "DejaVu Sans Mono".

Comment: Consolas. I am unable to install fonts

Comment: Then you will be unable to reach your goal.  "DejaVu Sans Mono" is the only font I've tried that works.  I've tried a couple of others -- Lucida Console and Liberation Mono, neither of which successfully printed the symbol in the console, whereas in WordPad they printed fine.  The DejaVu font works both in WordPad and in cmd.

Comment: Alright. Ill see if I can compile a c# program to echo the symbol or something.

Comment: Using what font?  Consolas doesn't have a glyph for ☢.  The language doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh,ok. Then I give up.