# Character replacement batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd, cyrillic

I'm trying to do a batch script using Windows command line to convert some characters for example:

```
É to Й
Ö to Ц
Ó to У
Ê to К
Å to Е
Í to Н
Ã to Г
Ø to Ш
Ù to Щ
Ç to З
```

with no success. That's because I am using a program that does not support a Cyrillic font.

And I have already the file with these words, like:

```
ОБОГРЕВ ЗОНЫ  1
ДАВЛЕНИЕ ЦВЕТА 1
...
and so on...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using unicode? or there are from extended ascii table?

Comment: for making std output more readable in `cmd` shell: `mode con cp select=855`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you'd like to convert the character set (alias code page) of a file so you can open and read it.
I'm assuming you are using a Windows computer.

Let's say that your file is **russian.txt** and when you open it with notepad, the characters doesn't make any sense. The **russian.txt** file's character encoding is most propably ANSI and it's code page is Windows-1251. 
Some words about character encoding:

- In ANSI one character is one byte long.

  - Different languages have different code pages: Windows-1251 = Russian, Windows-1252 = Western Languages (English, German, Swedish...), Windows-1253 = Greek ...
- In UTF-8 English characters are one byte long and non-English characters two bytes long.
- In Unicode all characters are two bytes long.
- UTF-8 and Unicode doesn't need code pages.

You can check the encoding by opening the file in notepad and clicking File, Save As. At the right bottom corner beside the Save-button you can see the encoding.

With some googling I found a site where you can do the character encoding conversion online. I Haven't tested it, but here's the address:

- http://i-tools.org/charset

I've made a script (= a small program) which changes the character encoding from any ANSI and code page combination to UTF-8 or Unicode or vice versa.

Let's say you have and English Windows computer and want to convert the **russian.txt** (ANSI / Windows-1251) to UTF-8. 
Here's how:

- Open this web-page and copy the script in it to the clipboard:

  - [VB6/VBScript change file encoding to ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182102/vb6-vbscript-change-file-encoding-to-ansi/22930900#22930900)
- Create a new file named ConvertCharset.vbs to the same folder, where the **russian.txt** is, say C:\Temp.
- Open the ConvertCharset.vbs in notepad (right click+edit) and paste.
- Open CMD (Windows-button+R, cmd, Enter).
- In CMD-window type (hit Enter-key at each end of the line):

`cd C:\Temp\
cscript ConvertCharset.vbs /InputCharset:Windows-1251 /OutputCharset:utf-8 /InputFile:russian.txt /OutputFile:russian_utf-8.txt`

Now the you can open the russian_utf-8.txt in notepad and you'll see the Russian characters OK.

More info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
- [VB6/VBScript change file encoding to ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182102/vb6-vbscript-change-file-encoding-to-ansi/22930900#22930900)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure my solution is for you, because I checked some of the characters in your example: The decimal value of **É** in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (Western Languages) is 201 and the same decimal value in [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (Russian) corresponds to **Й**. If you think my answer is good, vote for it, if not, ask me a question and I'll try to answer.