# Changing text file encoding to ANSI

Tags: excel, vba, notepad++, ansi

I need to convert some txt files to ANSI encoding. These files should have ANSI encoding according to Notepad++ encoding description.

I compare these files to a sample file which is identified by Notepad++ as ANSI encoded. These files should have ANSI encoding to be able to upload them to an old application.

I need to do it automatically as a part of VBA code which I also use to create the files from Excel data. Each time the macro pastes data from Excel to new workbook and saves as text file. Maybe it is possible to just choose encoding while saving Excel file but I didn't find the ANSI encoding in save options in Excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6/VBScript change file encoding to ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182102/vb6-vbscript-change-file-encoding-to-ansi)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that maybe the best way would be to open each text file in Notepad and save as choosing the ANSI encoding. Is it possible to do using Shell call in VBA ?