# How to convert files from csv with utf-8 to csv using vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ssis

I am using the code below within a script task in SSIS. The purpose of the code is to convert CSV files (with filenames starting with CO2) from UTF-8 encoding to standard CSV before loading them into a database table. However, the code is not converting the files as expected. Is the logic correct? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Public Sub Main()

    ' Set the folder path where the files are located
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "<path>"

    ' Set the file extension you want to filter (assuming all are .csv)
    Dim fileExt As String
    fileExt = "*.csv"

    ' Set the initial file to process
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "CO2 *" & fileExt)

    ' Loop through matching files
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        ' Construct the full file path
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = folderPath & fileName

        ' Open the file, convert and overwrite
        ConvertAndOverwriteCSV(filePath)

        ' Get the next file
        fileName = Dir()

    Loop
    MsgBox("Conversion completed for CO2 files.")
End Sub

Sub ConvertAndOverwriteCSV(filePath As String)
    Dim oExcel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Disable Excel UI elements
    oExcel.Visible = False
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

    Dim oWorkbook As Object
    oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    oWorkbook.SaveAs(FileName:=filePath & oWorkbook.Name, FileFormat:=6)

End Sub
```

Comment: What do *you* mean by "standard CSV"? UTF-8 encoding is pretty standard.
To change it, choose one of the other CSV options as `FileFormat` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: what I mean is CSV without UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Do you want UTF-8 to be converted to ANSI? If so, utf-8 encoding has a larger set of characters than ANSI, thus it's not possible to convert from ANSI to utf-8 without any loss. Of course, if there is no special characters able to be kept in UTF-8, it may work. Now, why do you need it that way? Converting UTF-8 in UTF-16 may be enough and also keeping most of special characters...

Comment: there are no special characters within the data - loss of data or the keeping of special characters is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Using `FileFormat:=6` is giving you a UTF-8 CSV with a BOM character at the start (see [Byte Order Mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark)

All of the other options on *my* installation will give a CSV without a BOM (this will vary for other people).

Try using `xlCSVMSDOS` instead i.e. `FileFormat:=24` Here is the reference link from my comment again
[XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

If you definitely want to convert to ANSI (I don't believe that you do, SSIS can cope with UTF-8 files) then I believe you cannot use `SaveAs` in Excel to achieve that. Even `xlTextMSDOS` (21) is giving a UTF-8 encoded file. To convert to ANSI you will need to use something like an `ADODB.Stream` object (N.B. `FileSystemObject` also produces UTF-8).
There is an example here [VB6/VBScript change file encoding to ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182102/vb6-vbscript-change-file-encoding-to-ansi).
The fact that it is rather a faff to achieve this should be giving you clues